# Como faço pra colocar uma imagem no lugar do botão preto? Exemplo: uma moeda?

Tags: html

```js
document.getElementById("bcen").style.width = "300px"; //Size

document.getElementById("bcen").style.height = "300px"; //Size
    
document.getElementById('bcen').style.fontSize="100px";   //size   
    
document.getElementById('bcen').style.color = 'white' 
    
document.getElementById('bcen').style.backgroundColor='black';
    
document.getElementById('bcen').style.borderRadius = "50%";
    
document.getElementById('bcen').style.outline = "none";
```

```html
<button id="bcen" onclick="if(--this.textContent<=0) alert('You\'ve won!');"  value="10">10</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode até deixar a linha abaixo se quiser que o elemento também tenha uma cor de fundo:

```
document.getElementById('bcen').style.backgroundColor='black';
```

Mas adicione também:

```
document.getElementById('bcen').style.backgroundImage='url(CAMINHO DA IMAGEM)';
document.getElementById('bcen').style.backgroundSize='cover';
```

O `style.backgroundImage` irá inserir uma imagem de fundo e o `style.backgroundSize='cover';` irá fazer com que a imagem de fundo ocupe todo o elemento.

**Exemplo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="bcen" onclick="if(--this.textContent<=0) alert('You\'ve won!');"  value="10">10</button>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("bcen").style.width =
"300px"; //Size
    document.getElementById("bcen").style.height =
"300px"; //Size

document.getElementById('bcen').style.fontSize="100px";   //size   

document.getElementById('bcen').style.color = 'white' 

document.getElementById('bcen').style.backgroundColor='black';
document.getElementById('bcen').style.backgroundImage='url(https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MzAwWDMwMA==/z/~z8AAOSwEK9UIcNC/$_35.JPG?set_id=2)';
document.getElementById('bcen').style.backgroundSize='cover';

document.getElementById('bcen').style.borderRadius = "50%";

document.getElementById('bcen').style.outline = "none";
      </script/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Beleza obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Por nada amigo!